# How can I select and remove an HTML element (its tags and content) in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

First of all, there is an "Emmet: Remove Tag" feature, but that only removes the wrapping of particular tags. It doesn't remove the entire element including the children within.

I'm looking for the same execution which removes the children as well. Saves a few seconds for those who edit HTML a lot.

In the example below, I want to remove the whole `<ul>` element by using an emmet or similar command.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Dummy HTML Snippet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>This is a dummy HTML snippet with nested tags.</p>
    <div>
        <h2>A Nested Section</h2>
        <p>This is a paragraph inside a div element.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li>List item 2</li>
            <li>List item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Back to the main content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- place the cursor on `<ul>` or `</ul>`
- execute command: **Emmet: Balance Outward**
- press `Delete`

If you need this a lot you can add a keybinding for the command **Emmet: Balance Outward**

If you place the cursor anywhere inside the `<ul>...</ul>` tag you can  select the `<ul>...</ul>` tag by applying the command/keybinding multiple times.

This also works with **Multi Cursor**.

Comment: Thank you. I assigend Ctrl+Shift+B to this.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: I think [rioV8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792474/11107541) (which was posted after mine) is better. I'm just leaving mine here if anyone's interested.

Put your caret after the `>` of the opening tag, then run the `Expand Selection` command twice (bound to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> by default), which should expand the selection to the elements tags and content, and then press your delete or backspace key. Technically you can start your cursor in any part of the element's source markup, but you'll just have to expand the selection more times.

Comment: This got me a little closer, I'll try incorporating this with automation. like excute this twice or thrice to select element & then delete.

Comment: @Hardik If you want, you can write a keyboard shortcut using [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands).

Answer (score 0):

based on: [@starball answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792341/13188881)

open the keybindings.json file from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) with the Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) command.

then add this to json file:

```
{
    "command": "runCommands",
    "key": "shift+alt+right", // whatever keybinding
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
            "editor.action.smartSelect.expand"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now by pressing **`Shift`+`Alt`+`Right`** `Expand Selection` runs twice and you  do what you want

Note: you can edit keybind with whatever keybind you want